# Help with report

Tags: reporting

I have the following setup

Sensitive Information >-- User --< Opportunities

I want to be able to pull a report that reports on all three objects. This, unfortunately does not work. I can either only link Sensitive Information and User, or User and Opportunities.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

I already thought whether it would be possible to create a lookup from User to Sensitive Information, but it is not allowed to create Lookup fields on the User object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions at your disposal in current situation

> **Solution#1-[Joined Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_joined_format_concepts.htm&type=0)**

1. Create a report on Sensitive Information and User
2. Create another report on User and Opportunities
3. Goto to the first report and then change the report type to 'Joined Report' and then add the second report block.

> **Solution#2- Create VF Page to display data**

1. Create a [wrapper class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class)
2. Have all columns you need
3. Build your wrapper class columns by processing the objects (User, Sensitive information, and Opportunities).
4. Bind your list of wrapper class to the VF page [Page Block Table](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm) or data table component.